# Creating a dynamic model relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have three models User.php, Profile.php, CorporateProfile.php and trying to creating a dynamic relationship between the User,profile, corporateprofile models depending a attribute of the user model.
Heres my code for the user model

```
    <?php 

        use Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\Eloquent\User as SentryModel;

        class User extends SentryModel
        {
            protected $with = array('groups');

            public function profile()
            {
                if($this->type == 1) {
                    return $this->hasOne('\K1\Data\Models\Profile','user_id');
                }
                elseif($this->type == 2) {
                    return $this->hasOne('\K1\Data\Models\CorporateProfile', 'user_id');
                }
            }
}
```

It works for a user model with type = 1 but not for type = 2.
How can i get this working correctly

Comment: Read this http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#polymorphic-relations

Answer (score 0):

*Maybe* this should work, but the comparison to `1` is a *truthy* comparison?

So if `$this->type` is not of type `int`, but instead `string` (because sometimes MySQL just does these things...), then the first `if` only checks if the string exists (is true). So what you want is

```
if((int) $this->type === 1) {
    return $this->hasOne('\K1\Data\Models\Profile','user_id');
}
elseif((int) $this->type === 2) {
    return $this->hasOne('\K1\Data\Models\CorporateProfile', 'user_id');
}
```

(Polymorphic relations are also a safe bet.)